# Automatically updating files from another branch

Tags: git, github, githooks, github-pages

My situation is the following: I have two branches, master and gh-pages. There are some files that are common between those branches, and I have to manually sync them with `git cherry-pick`.

That's a tedious and error-prone task, so I wanted to know if there is a way to do this automatically, for example using some git hook(maybe verifying if those common files are exclusively present, or using some command-line flag.

One example of my workflow would be:

```
git checkout master
... 
git add common-file1.txt
git commit -m "did something with that file"
git checkout gh-pages
git cherry-pick master's HEAD
```

To clarify, only some of the files are "shared" between those branches, they are not the same branch, and each have some files that the other doesn't. When I do `git cherry-pick`, I'm getting a commit that only have some of these common files in it.

Comment: It sounds like your two branches are two divergent-yet-parallel streams: perhaps fixing the structure of the project (split the common files into a [git submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), for example) would solve the underlying issue rather than the symptoms?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have considered this solution before, and I'm a little hesitant to use it because it would change the file structure of the `gh-pages` branch, breaking some links of the github page. If I don't find any other solution, I may have to use a git submodule after all.

Comment: @john What did you end up doing in the end?. I've a similar requirement where my 'master' build generates content that i want to check in to my 'gh-pages' branch.

Comment: oh well, I deleted my master branch and just used the gh-pages branch, but I am going to take a look at static site generation tools such as Grain and Jekyll when I have the time

Answer (score -1):

You mean [git merge](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)? That's the most common way to "sync" between branches. First "git checkout" the target branch, second "git merge" the source branch. It's all in the [book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) and in this case better than cherry-picking because it (potentially) doesn't create new commits.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. I added a clarification to my question. Thanks